# Why is the sum of bitwise AND and bitwise XOR equal to bitwise OR?

Tags: bit-manipulation

Is there a reason why this happens?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int i, j; //Takes i as 0 with short

    printf("Enter two integers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);

    printf("\n%d & %d = %d\n", i, j, (i & j));
    printf("\n%d ^ %d = %d\n", i, j, (i ^ j));
    printf("\n%d | %d = %d\n", i, j, (i | j));

    if ((i | j) == (i & j) + (i ^ j))
        printf("\nYES\n");
    else
        printf("\nNO\n");
}
```

Comment: You could make a truth table to verify it.  The key is that if `a,b` are two bits, then `a&b` and `a^b` cannot both be 1, and so adding them never causes a carry.

Answer (score 4):

First note that `i & j` and `i ^ j` are *disjoint*: if a bit is set in one of them, the corresponding bit is necessarily reset in the other. That's a consequence of the truth tables of AND and XOR. AND has only a single row with a 1 in it, and XOR has a 0 in that row, so they're never simultaneously both 1.

That means we can forget about the special complications of addition (there is no carry, which makes addition purely bitwise: equivalent to both OR and XOR), and analyze this expression as if we were dealing with just booleans.

One way to look at it is that `i & j` exactly compensates for the case that `i ^ j` does not cover. If you write out the truth tables: (only 1 bit shown)

```
i j i&j i^j (i&j)|(i^j)
0 0  0   0       0
0 1  0   1       1
1 0  0   1       1
1 1  1   0       1
```

The last column has values identical to `i | j`.

Answer (score 1):

By using Logic gate truth table we can easily find how it works.

```
+---+---+------------+-----------+------------+
| A | B | AND output | OR output | XOR output |
+---+---+------------+-----------+------------+
| 0 | 0 |          0 |         0 |          0 |
| 0 | 1 |          0 |         1 |          1 |
| 1 | 0 |          0 |         1 |          1 |
| 1 | 1 |          1 |         1 |          0 |
+---+---+------------+-----------+------------+
```

For instance, let `i = 5, j = 6`. In binary we get `i = 00000101, j = 00000110`.

```
(i | j) = (00000101 | 00000110) = 01101111
(i & j) = (00000101 & 00000110) = 01100100
(i ^ j) = (00000101 ^ 00000110) = 00001011

(i & j) + (i ^ j) = 01100100 + 00001011 = 01101111 = (i | j)
```

Therefor, `(i | j) = (i & j) + (i ^ j)`